# Using websocketcpp for writing a simple client

Tags: c++, client, websocket++

after hours of trying to correctly set up boost and websocket++, i am now trying to implement a simple client in websocket++ which *JUST* sends some messages to the server.

The only example i could find is an echoing client, which just reacts OnMessage(). Is there no other way to send messages to the socket? or are there some other events i need to define, like OnConnection() or WhileRunning() or something?

I'm speaking of Zaphohyd Websocket++ "Echo_Client". The simple broadcast server is working like i want it to, but i have problems with the client, since there are no examples out there simply sending messages to the socket.

Thanks!

Comment: But the echo client example *is* "simply sending messages to the socket", it just happens to do so in response to messages it receives. Once you have the connection, just send the messages you want to send.

Comment: you're right, it just wasn't fitting my understanding how it should work. the whole websocket++ overhead is to much for me i think. nonetheless i found the telemetry client, on which now try to build on. thanks